# update unique indexed column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a unique indexed column A with integer in it. I'd like it to increment by 1, in Oracle I do: update table set A=A+1 and it worked. But in mySQL, it give me the following error:
- MySQL Database Error: Duplicate entry '2' for key 1. I have three rows in the table with value: 1, 2 and 3 individually. I know why it gives me this error. But how do I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: So this works in Oracle?

Comment: How you solve it depends on what you want to happen. Do you want to delete the OTHER row where a=2? Do you want to have two rows where a=2? Tell us what is the correct end result, and then someone can help you get there.

Comment: Erm, the OP would want the row that equals '2' to become '3'

Comment: Strawberry, yes, in Oracle you can do this without order by desc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You receive this error because your `UPDATE TABLE SET A = A + 1`, when updating the first ROW from 1 to 2 (1+1), it will get conflict with your second ROW, because there already is a ROW with ID = 2.

You have to do it descender from the last ROW to the first, do you have to alter your query to this:

`UPDATE TABLE SET ID = ID + 1 ORDER By ID DESC;`

The `DESC` clause will make the updates from the bottom of your table, so it won't find any duplicate ID in his path...

Comment: just for the record, I did not copy that answer from Ike, but he was faster to answer while I was still typing to explain WHY that error happened. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using an `ORDER BY`:

```
update table 
set A=A+1
order by A desc
```

Comment: I genuinely didn't know that!