# Update lot of data, date ( +1hour ), contraints uniq

Tags: mysql, date

I try to add 1hours for each value after specific date...

I have table like this :

```
Colonne Type
id  int(11)
date    datetime    
value   double  
kind    varchar(190)    
data_id int(11) NULL
```

I have uniq constraints on 'date' . 'kind' . 'data_id'

I try :

```
update data set `date` = ADDTIME(`date`, '01:00:00') WHERE `date` > '2019-03-31 02:00:00';
```

But i get Error

> Duplicate entry '2019-03-31 04:05:00-ManualDataValue-1' for key 'UNIQ_DATE_KIND_DATA_ID

I understand the error, the value exists, but I need to "move" all data ... 
So if the request is performed in one block and the unique constraints is checked at the end, technically there is no error ...

How to perform this ? 
( PS: SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `date` > '2019-03-31 02:00:00'  return 1,198,778 entry, so i can't do this manualy :/ )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [update unique indexed column in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198733/update-unique-indexed-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
update data set `date` = ADDTIME(`date`, '01:00:00') WHERE `date` > '2019-03-31 02:00:00' ORDER By date DESC
```

See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198733/update-unique-indexed-column-in-mysql) for more explanations.